# Drag & Drop canvas trimmer for transparent PNGs?

Tags: gratis, osx, image-processing, png

I need to take images that are exported and quickly trim off the transparent cruft around the images that are exported. The part to be removed will always be 100% transparent.

Traditionally I use Sketch, PS, or FW, etc. to do this, but I felt it would be nice if a program like [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/mac) would either integrate this or if there was another option that would enable simple drag and drop functionality such as this.

Comment: Yep. I've actually asked the dev of ImageOptim to add this as a feature as well since it would be useful: https://github.com/ImageOptim/ImageOptim/issues/158

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give [XnConvert](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/) a try. Lots under the hood and a real powerhouse yet it's dead simple to use.

- Does drag & drop batch processing
- Does it lightning fast
- Highly configurable re: operations/export settings
- Will play nice with damn near any image format you throw at it
- Cross platform freeware

Operations are stackable and there are about 80 of them to choose from. `Add action > Image > Automatic crop` should get you where you wanna be.